# Provide both authorized and unauthorized endpoints in MVC API (Routing?)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I want to provide both authorized and unauthorized methods in my API.

Let's say I have thing controller and will implement an endpoint for getting things.

I want to provide access to authorized request to: `website.com/api/secure/thing/`

I want to provide access to unauthorized request to: `website.com/api/insecure/thing/`

```
public class Thing : ApiController
{
    public IThingRepository  ThingRepository { get; set; }

    [ActionName("Index"), HttpGet]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetThing(string id)
    {
        return Ok(ThingRepository.get(Id) );
    }
}
```

I know if I use `[AllowAnonymous]` will let unauthorized request towards the method. But how can I have other method redirected to same action?

Thanks

PS1: It is temporary requirement. We want to add authorization to the API methods, but in the meanwhile we still want to serve the users with old application that doesn't use authorization.

PS2: We provide a string like `website.com/api/something` to a mobile application that consumes the web API. The mobile app completes the path to the API methods (".../thing"). A new version of the mobile app will include authorization tokens along with the requests. So both the old (insecure) and new mobile app should find the endpoint "thing". We could of course just ignore the tokens and keep it only insecure for a while.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Why don't you copy the method's contents? Or send a Redirect response? Or make a third helper method both actions call?

Comment: You mean redirect the request from the non-authenticated to the authenticated version?

Comment: The other way around. You'd run into authentication. I assume you have two actions to handle both routes? Then kill (delete) the action or force a 301 redirection when you retire one of the endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little bit late for you, but i guess still relevant as it was for me on a requirement just now.
You could solve it with something like this. I you have a more complex policy maybe you could create a custom attribute to handle those policies.

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet("samepath")]
    public ActionResult<string> One()
    {
        if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return "auth";
        }
        return "no auth";
    }
```

Comment: The suggestion to use an attribute is solid and how a project I worked on years ago solved the problem, and doesn't really require much code (just a few lines). I would discourage people from wrapping specific sections of a controller action in access checks, in favor of providing separate actions for authorized and unauthenticated callers, with both calling common code from a private method, to avoid unnecessary duplication. Or, the clumsy but easy way is to define actions with different paths, for each case, and making the caller responsible for calling the right one.